# How can I get the top categories by join in LINQ?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I am working on classified ads project I am facing problem to get top categories where most  ads are posted every category have sub category also.

I made query but it is working for sub category ads I want if any category have no sub category then parent category ads should counted.

```
var result = (from c in db.Category 
              join a in db.Ad on c.CategoryId equals a.CategoryId 
              where c.ParentId != null 
              group c by c.ParentId into g 
              select new { cat = g.Key, a = g.Count() })
                .OrderBy(c => c.cat)
                .OrderByDescending(a => a.a);
```

My Category Table is like this

CategoryId  ----- ParentId -----Name

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this could be done with separate queries:

Get a list of categories that don't have any parentId set:

```
var resultsWithoutSubs = from c in db.Category
             where c.ParentId == null 
               && !result.Any(r => cat == c.CategoryId)
             select c;
```

Based on the list above, repeat the original query:

```
var counts =  from c in resultsWithoutSubs
          join a in dbAd on c.CategoryId equals a.CategoryId
          group c by c.CategoryId into g
          select new {cat = g. Key, a = g.Count};
```

Then you should be able to Union these the first and the last list and sort the results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var results = db.Category
    .Join(db.Ad, cat => cat.CategoryId, 
          ad => ad.CategoryId, (cat, ad) => new { cat, ad } )
    .Where (c => !dbCategory
      .Any (d => c.cat.CategoryId == d.ParentId) && c.cat.ParentId == null)
     .GroupBy (c => c.cat.CategoryId) 
     .Select (g => new  
        { cat = g.Key, a = g.Count () } 
);
```

Comment: I want to count ads it but it is counting sub categories of parent category

Comment: @StackMe, I think I understand now what you are asking. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you this is useful for me